# jQuery help remove div after append

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have some problem with jQuery, won't to remove div after is created...here is the code

```
$('.del').on('click', function() {
        //delItem = $(this);
        var data_id = $(this).attr('rel');
        $.post('index/xhrDelete', {'data_id': data_id}, function(o) {
            //delItem.parent().remove(); // i have tried this too
            $(this).parent().remove();
        }, 'json');
        return false;
});
```

it removes div but when i refresh manually...but i want to be without refreshing the page
here is html....

```
<div>
     ccc
     <a class="del" href="#" rel="5">X</a>
</div>
<div>
test
     <a class="del" href="#" rel="21">X</a>
```

testd
        X

Comment: You are not `.remove()`-ing correct element. Does `console.log($(this).parent())` return anything?

Comment: @Glavić so can you tell me how is rite to do?

Comment: Are you sure your ajax call goes to success callback. Check your network console. Else your commented out approach should work just fine.

Comment: @PSL sorry but i'm new to jQuery can you explain how to check jQuery callback...

Comment: Just put a console.log inside the callback. or check the network console in your browser, it will tell if your ajax call failed or not.

Comment: callback is fine, becouse i have a code with jQuery that inserts data...and jQuery updating my page without refreshing manually...there i have not problems...just when removing

Comment: @Al3x_F4nt0m: you should at least learn how to use `console.log()` command before asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Give a shot with this :

```
$('.del').on('click', function(e) { // Notice the 'e' in the function
    $this = $(e.target); // Use it to retrieve the element that fired the event and turn it into a jQuery object
    var data_id = $(this).attr('rel');
    $.post('index/xhrDelete', {'data_id': data_id}, function(o) {
        $this.parent().remove(); // You just need to remove its parent
    }, 'json');

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

```
$('.del').on('click', function() {
       var self=this;
        var data_id = $(self).attr('rel');
        $.post('index/xhrDelete', {'data_id': data_id}, function(o) {
            //delItem.parent().remove(); // i have tried this too
            $(self).parent().remove();
        }, 'json');
        return false;
});
```

Hope it helps....